# Android studio not founded

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I am starting a new project with react-native. I had used expo before but now I'm trying to use Android Studio for my development. But Vs is not finding the android studio and emulator I  created. I've added the path to systems but it is still not working? I am using Windows 11, Is there anything you recommend?

This is the result I get when I run React-native doctor
`

````
**npx @react-native-community/cli doctor
Common
 ✓ Node.js
 ✓ npm

Android
 ✓ JDK
 ✓ Android Studio - Required for building and installing your app on Android
 ✖ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android
   - Versions found: N/A
   - Version supported: 31.0.0
 ✓ ANDROID_HOME

Errors:   1
Warnings: 0
```**
`
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled and installed again android studio and react-native then it worked. I'm not exactly sure why!